# Do I need to make a Custom Data Provider if I want to OData + EF + my own contracts?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, odata, wcf-data-services

I am making an OData (WCF Data Service) endpoint using Entity Framework (EF) for my company.

We have realized that standard OData + EF couples us too closely to the database][1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx). So I am looking to add another layer between EF and OData.

So my question is: Do I need to make a [Custom Data Service Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) or is there a way I can wire up the OData [Reflection Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/06/11/tip-56-writing-an-odata-service-using-the-reflection-provider.aspx) to EF?  I have read about the Reflection Provider and it seems to work with in-memory stuff only.  I don't know how to wire that up to EF's way of loading data.

Note: My OData services are Read Only.  I don't need them to be updateable.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem Reflection provider should meet all your requirements. You just need to make some class which will expose properties with `IQueryable<>` of your custom objects. Reflection provider doesn't work with memory stuff only - it just needs a class to explore with reflection but implementation of that class is up to you. Linq-to-Sql contexts are also exposed through reflection provider and they are definitely not only in-memory stuff.

The problem which you will have is translating queries to your custom objects into queries to your entities because that cannot be translated natively.